# error on pipe in bash script

Tags: bash

part of my bash script is

```
A="-a"
B="|more"
ls $A $B
```

when executing this script, it complained "|more" not found.
How to use pipelines in bash script commands then please?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
eval "ls $A $B"
```

?

Comment: `eval` is dangerous! What if `A='\`rm -rf'` and `B='/\`'`?

Comment: @amphetamachine: Yes, it *is* dangerous, as is the idea to make a single command out of bits the way the OP wants it.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you may be trying for is implementing some sort of variable that controls whether the data is piped through a pager.

You may be better off using `alias`:

```
if [ "$USING_PAGER" -ne 0 ]; then
    alias B='more'
else
    alias B='cat'
fi

ls $A |B
```

Comment: Very nice. If the script is for general (public) use (which is probably oftener the case than not), this approach is much safer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -a |more
```

also fails - there is no such command in bash.

Comment: actually, most modern bashs are lax enough to allow "|more" without the space.

Comment: @cularis: Petar is possibly talking specifically about `more`, not `|more`. (Probably because it should be `less`.)

Comment: yeah exactly, sorry, I got distracted :)